# Give text of selected tab a different color using ViewPagerIndicator

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, viewpagerindicator

I've tried to let the [SampleTabsStyled demo](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/blob/master/sample/src/com/viewpagerindicator/sample/SampleTabsStyled.java) from the [ViewPagerIndicator](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator) change the color of the text of the currently selected tab without success.

However, the [SampleTitlesStyledTheme demo](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/blob/master/sample/src/com/viewpagerindicator/sample/SampleTitlesStyledTheme.java) does change its text color when switching between titles/tabs.

When looking inside the [styles xml](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator/blob/master/sample/res/values/styles.xml):

```xml
<resources>
    ...
    <style name="CustomTitlePageIndicator">
        <item name="android:background">#18FF0000</item>
        <item name="footerColor">#FFAA2222</item>
        <item name="footerLineHeight">1dp</item>
        <item name="footerIndicatorHeight">3dp</item>
        <item name="footerIndicatorStyle">underline</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#AA000000</item>
        <item name="selectedColor">#FF000000</item>
        <item name="selectedBold">true</item>
    </style>
    ...
    <style name="CustomTabPageIndicator" parent="Widget.TabPageIndicator">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/custom_tab_indicator</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">@style/CustomTabPageIndicator.Text</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#FF555555</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
        <item name="android:divider">@drawable/custom_tab_indicator_divider</item>
        <item name="android:dividerPadding">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:showDividers">middle</item>
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">8dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">8dp</item>
        <item name="android:fadingEdge">horizontal</item>
        <item name="android:fadingEdgeLength">8dp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="CustomTabPageIndicator.Text" parent="android:TextAppearance.Medium">
        <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    </style>
    ...
</resources>
```

I see that the `SampleTitlesStyledTheme` demo uses the `CustomTitlePageIndicator` style, which defines a `selectedColor` item. So (perhaps naively) I thought to add

```xml
<item name="selectedColor">#FF000000</item>
```

to the style the `SampleTabsStyled` demo is using, `CustomTabPageIndicator`, but, alas, that didn't work.

The question seems obvious, but I'll ask anyway: is there a way (using the present styles xml) to let the currently selected text of a tab in the `SampleTabsStyled` demo have a different color than the other tabs? If so, how?

#### EDIT

Oh, and I'm using this in combination with ActionBarSherlock, in case that is important...

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Assuming  you don't mind creating an extra xml, first try include the attribute `android:textColor` in your `CustomTabPageIndicator.Text` (or `CustomTabPageIndicator`) like this:

```
<style name="CustomTabPageIndicator.Text" parent="android:TextAppearance.Medium">
    <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/tab_text_color</item>
    ...
</style>
```

where `tab_text_color.xml` is put under res/drawable folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:color="@color/text_tab_selected" />
    <item
        android:state_selected="false"
        android:color="@color/text_tab_unselected" />
</selector>
```

Finally, just define the two colors `@color/text_tab_selected` and `@color/text_tab_unselected` in your color resource file `colors.xml` located in res/values folder (create one if it does not exist already). For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="text_tab_selected">#FF000000</color>
    <color name="text_tab_unselected">#FF555555</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: I could have sworn I tried something like that, but I must have goofed up somewhere. I only had to change `android:textColor` into `android:color` in the **tab_text_color.xml** file after which it worked like a charm. Many thanks Neoh!

Comment: Yes, I've edited the answer to reflect what you really asked :)

Comment: I already edited with the correct value (which is `android:color`). When I do `android:textColor`, a runtime exception is thrown and the following is on my logcat: *"Binary XML file line #5: <item> tag requires a 'android:color' attribute."*. I've edited your answer to contain the correct variant.

Answer (score 16):

> Try this
>
> Simplest way

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                android:id="@+id/tabs"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:tabTextColor="@color/White"
                app:tabSelectedTextColor="@color/Blue"
                app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/Yellow"
                app:tabMode="fixed"
                app:tabGravity="fill"/>
```

> Don't forgot to add this Dependency

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```